# Which architectural pattern does Meteor.js use?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, meteor, architecture

I know very well the MVC pattern, however Meteor does not natively seem to follow any pattern like it.

Which architectural pattern is used when developing Meteor apps?

Comment: This will be very very tricky to answer. Meteor has a unique and complex architecture, which shines in elegance with the whole data distribution craze and stuff. Here's a nice [picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/master/images/Meteor%20Architecture%20-%20Dev%20to%20Prod.jpg) from [awatson's Meteor cookbook](https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook). I fear if you're looking for a bunch of letters (MVC, MVVC, ...) it would be very long to write (and funny to pronounce). Plus, Meteor is pretty open to modifications, so even such an acronym could be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say `MVVM` when you're using [reactive source](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/), where you can make data change and the view will be updated my Meteor automatically.

One thing worth to mention is the `client-server` of Meteor, they're basically tied together with [Websocket](https://www.meteor.com/ddp). Which enable developer create `Pub/Sub` or `Observer` for both data and view easily. And you don't have to deal with too much `request/response` like traditional http-based application.

Comment: Nice answer. I'ma dig up more on MVVM.